# Axios Token authorization 401 results in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I tried to call a REST api endpoint in my Django project. So far its working when using curl, postman. I have the problem when I tried calling it in my django template frontend with Axios.
As I inspected network tab,  the request return 401, sending both params and token.

```
axios.get(url,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Token 0ca677330f947335a72572bdbdfe305ae7dd8ba6'},params:params})
```

I also tried

```
 return axios({
                  method: 'get',
                  url: url,
                  headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Token 0ca677330f947335a72572bdbdfe305ae7dd8ba6'
                    },
                    params: params
                })
```

And Still got 401.

Any idea?

UPDATE

Now I figure out the reason.When i tried in Google incognito, it works, I can confirm this by using other browser like firefox,now for my updated question, how to delete or refresh to delete cache? I tried everything in chrome's developer console by deleting cache in Application Tab

Comment: 301 is a redirect, where are you getting redirected to?

Comment: 401 is Unauthorized Error so probably your token had expired or incorrect.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb as a mentioned it works with curl or postman.

Comment: Actually one of our app consumer works very well, using native curl. I think there's an specific configurations needed if accessing tru Javascript.I already tried Jquery way, still I got 401

Comment: Did you get the answer to this, am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: same problem here @ira any luck????

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings.py file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

and make sure `TokenAuthentication` is at the top.

Comment: Already did this.Nothing works. The frontend is in same origin as the api, maybe theres something to add in settings

Comment: Since you are getting 401 this shouldn't be a cors issue

Comment: My suspect is it didn't forward the Authorization-Header to the WSGI-Process.Just my guess.

Comment: have you added this to settings.py `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['authorization',]` ? in case you are using django-cors-headers